# How do I show multiple post types? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to create multiple post types (image with description & a thought (body of text)) and when I use my controller to show the posts on a page called 'vault' nothing appears.

**Models**

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :type, presence: true

  has_one_attached :image
  validate :image_presence

  def image_presence
    errors.add(:image, "can't be blank") unless image.attached?
  end
end
```

**image_post.rb**

```
class ImagePost < Post
  validates :image, presence: true

end
```

**thought_post.rb**

```
class ThoughtPost < Post
  validates :thought, presence: true
end
```

**Controller to show all users posts for page called 'Vault'**

```
class VaultController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @posts = current_user.posts.all
  end

end
```

**Posts migration**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :description
      t.text :thought
      t.string :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1>Vault</h1>
<p>See Posts Here:</p>

<div class="user-images">
    <% @posts.each do |post|%>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <%=link_to post_path(post) do %>
        <%=image_tag post.image %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load a Rails console, then load your user, and try to access the `posts` relationship of your user.
You will see the SQL debugging inside the console and will be able to see more easily if it is correctly linked to any posts or not.

Comment: I have tried this and they are definitely associated with the user and I can definitely create each type of post. I simply want to render ALL types of posts on my vault page. Still have the issue unfortunately !